# Add A Row - Not adding a row to bottom when previous rows are hidden

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have an order form (hosted by Jotform.com) that's connected to a Google Sheet via the API through a company called Integromat.com. Everything has worked great for years but I received an email from Integromat.com on Friday that we were using a legacy version of the Google Sheets module and we needed to update before that legacy version stopped working.

I updated our modules (which I assume just updates the Google Sheets API?) and now I'm encountering a problem that I'm not sure how to fix. Integromat is claiming that "Unfortunately this behavior comes directly from Google Sheet's and we can't avoid it." but I question that.

My problem: The sheet that receives the order form data is updated properly so long as the very last row of filled data is unhidden. But we hide rows as orders are completed and if all the rows are hidden and a new order comes in a row is added at the top of the Sheet (row 2 since we have a header that's never hidden in row 1) which in turn throws off several other Sheets that are connected to the order sheet.

Before the update, the add a row function didn't care if rows were hidden or not. But since the update it's like it can't tell if data is contained in hidden rows or not and just proceeds to insert a new row at the top.

Is Integromat correct that this is now unavoidable? Or is there a solution that I can implement or tell them to implement?

The workaround for now will be that we don't hide orders in that sheet but that's not a great long-term solution for us.

Comment: I just tested this with a sample sheet and for me the data is being detected with or without being hidden.
Is unclear to me if you are actually inserting the data in the sheets through the API or is one of your third party services. But this seems like an easy workaround. Maybe a sample sheet and a snippet of your code could help debug this.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm using a third party service called Integromat.com. They are telling me it's a Google API issue so I wanted to investigate for myself. It seems the issue is on their end if you are able to get it to work so I'll contact them again.

Comment: Don't you have access to the API requests of the sheets? Pretty sure you can read document data even when the rows are hidden. And upon reading then you can  decide where to insert. But it's hard to tell who's fault without knowing the actual interaction with the API.

Comment: I'm not sure. To be honest, this is a little over my head. There's a history section inside the third party software where I can see some raw data so maybe that's what you're talking about?

Comment: Bundle 1Collection
Mode select
ValuesCollection
Date (A) 01/29/2020
Time (B) 10:55 AM
Name (C) John Doe
Address (D) 1055-2 Test
Sheet Data
Spreadsheet 1seSvBhZYKEZlRPPOMFl_wbztkt93uhrquy3qTmQQH1A
Table contains headers true
Insert data option INSERT_ROWS
Value input option USER_ENTERED
OUTPUT
Bundle 1Collection
Spreadsheet ID 1seSvBhZYKEZlRPPOMFl_wbztkt93uhrquy3qTmQQH1A
Table Range Data!A1:D1
UpdatesCollection
Spreadsheet ID 1seSvBhZYKEZlRPPOMFl_wbztkt93uhrquy3qTmQQH1A
Updated range Data!A2:D2
Updated rows 1
Updated columns 4
Updated cells 4
Sheet Data
Row Number 2

Comment: That was a test I just did on a new sheet and form I created for testing. When that ran, the sheet had data in rows 1-5 but rows 2-5 were hidden. The data was incorrectly added to row 2 which I can see in the raw data I just posted at the very end. If rows 2-5 were shown, it would have added the data to row 6 which is where I want it

Comment: I think this is a problem with the implementation of your third party service. It's a change that of course is doable and very easy to fix. But upon using their service you will depend on them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be caused by the first cell of the caption. It seems like integromat (aka make) can't handle it and thinks there is no caption. Then it just adds the new entry as the first line. Once the very first cell in the title contains data, it should work again.